# Safari не отображает цвет кнопки

Tags: html, html5, css3, safari

Добрый день, такая проблема, во всех браузерах отображается нормально кнопка с определенным цветом, а в сафари на мобильном устройстве она серая. Уже по разному пробовал прописывать. Помогите пожалуйста.

```css
    .form__send {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 9px;
    background: #77c364!important;
    background-color: #77c364!important;
    background-color: rgb(119, 195, 100)!important;
    background-color: vec3(0.47, 0.76, 0.39)!important;
    padding: 8px 15px!important;
    border: 0!important;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(91, 162, 73, 1)!important;
    font-size: 14px!important;
    font-weight: 600!important;
    cursor: pointer}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" id="ajaxform">

                <div class="col-9">

                    <input id="name" size="32" maxlength="36" type="text" name="name" size="40" class="form__input name-input" placeholder="Iмя" val="">

                    <input id="email" size="32" maxlength="36" type="email" name="email" size="40" class="form__input email-input" placeholder="E-Mail" val="">

                    <textarea id="message" cols="25" rows="10" name="message" class="form__input text-area" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Паведамленне" val=""></textarea>

                    <input id="send" class="form__send" type="submit" name="submit" value="Даслаць">

                </div>

            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте это свойство

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Comment: Кстати, хотел спросить, надо ли к этому свойству дописывать префиксы `-moz-` `-ms-` `-o-`, или пустая трата времени?

Comment: для кнопок достаточно и без префиксов. Более детально https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/